# I need some helps to reduce time running test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I got my problem at running this unit test. My problem is when I running this unit test, it took about 2000ms or more to get the data from that http.get, that's cause time out error while mocha test is support time 2000ms. To fix this, I have to put this.timeout(3000) or so, my question is: is there anyway to refactor my code to get the data faster so that my unit test time is reduce lower than 2000ms? Thank you for your concerning about my problem. Have a nice day of working guys.

```
describe('Test api Share of voice', () => {
  let apiLink = app.get("apiTestLink") + "/api/<link>";
  it('Status Code = 200', function(done) {
    this.timeout(constant.MAX_WAIT);
    http.get(apiLink, function(res) {
      assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200);
      done();
    });
  });
  //some tests
});
```

Comment: Ideally, you do not call http request in unit test. You mock services and pass hard-coded data as response. Unit test is to check *your code given all other dependencies are working fine*

Comment: nothing in javascript can speed up the internet -you're limited to the bandwidth you have

Comment: calling a real api is not a good way to go. You can use one of two approaches. A) Mock http response in test (there are several libs for that like nock). B) Use snapshot testing to stub http response.